# How do I add Webform-CiviCRM tokens into Webform emails?

Tags: webforms, tokens, civicrm

The following is the HTML from a form I have created using the [Webform CiviCRM Integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm) module.

```
<input class="civicrm-enabled form-text required" type="text" id="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-fieldset-fieldset-parent-civicrm-1-contact-1-contact-first-name" name="submitted[civicrm_1_contact_1_fieldset_fieldset][parent][civicrm_1_contact_1_contact_first_name]" value="" size="20" maxlength="128">
```

Based on the documentation, it appears I might need to use: `[submission:values:civicrm_1_contact_1_contact_first_name]`

But no values are passed using `civicrm_1_contact_1_contact_first_name` as the field key.

Any insight?

Comment: CiviCRM has started it's own StackExchange site at http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/.  It's still in private beta mode, but anyone who's already a member can invite you.  If you send me a message using my Drupal.org contact form at https://www.drupal.org/user/48877/contact, I'll send you and invite.  You are much more likely to get an answer to this in that QA site.